# Determine the generating function for the sequence $h_0, h_1, h_2, ...., h_n, ...,$ where $h_n$ is the number of n-combinations of S

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I'm trying to solve this problem : Let S be the multiset {$∞ * e_1$, $∞ * e_2$, $∞ * e_3$, $∞ * e_4$}. Determine the generating function for the sequence $h_0, h_1, h_2, ...., h_n, ...,$ where $h_n$ is the number of n-combinations of S with the following added restrictions:

1) The element $e_1$ does not occur, and $e_2$ occurs at most once.
2) The element $e_1$ occurs 1, 3, or 11 times, and the element $e_2$ occurs 2, 4, or 5 times.

My attempt : 
For the 1), I thought that the generating series 
$g(x) = (1+x+x^2+...)(1+x+x^2+...)(1+x)$ ; Namely, the first term was because of $e_3$ and the second one was because of $e_4$, and the last term was because of $e_2$

For the 2), I thought that the generating series 
$g(x) = (1+x+x^2+...)(1+x+x^2+...)(x+x^3+x^11)(x^2+x^4+x^5)$ ; Namely, the first term was because of $e_3$ and the second one was because of $e_4$, and the third term was because of $e_1$ the last term was because of $e_2$

Is this correct attempt? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those two expressions are correct, but we can write them neater. It is well-known that
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots=\frac1{1-x}$$
so the first series can be shortened to
$$\frac{1+x}{(1-x)^2}$$
while the second series can be shortened to
$$\frac{(x+x^3+x^{11})(x^2+x^4+x^5)}{(1-x)^2}$$
Incidentally, the first series gives the odd numbers in their entirety.